# Sum a field based on a filter and return that total to use a LAG function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, lag

This query contains a sum dollar amount and a date (month and year only) of which that sum belongs to. Then, I have a LAG function providing the dollar amount from prior month with its prior date, needed to calculate a difference/variance of month over month (not shown but if prior and current amounts are the same, difference is zero).

However, the LAG function assumes "prior row" as one month per row and when there are two+ entries for one particular month, the LAG breaks. **I need to group the sums by each month to return one grand total per month (per row), and only then apply the LAG, but not sure how.**

Here's the current query:

```
SELECT  
    [Account Name]
    , SUM([Extended Price]) [EP_Sum]
    , TRY_PARSE([Service Month] AS DATE) [ServiceMonthClean] -- handles exception by adding 'null' to bad data, and thus does not require where clause filters.
    , LAG(SUM([Extended Price]), 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION by [Account Name] order by [Service Month] asc) as [ExtPrice Lag Prior Month]
    , [Bill Date]        
FROM tables_with_joins        
WHERE 1 = 1        
GROUP BY [Service Month], [Account Name], [Account Number], [Bill Date]
ORDER BY [Service Month] desc, [Account Name] asc
```

Here's the result:

```
Account Name    EP_Sum  ServiceMonthClean   ExtPrice Lag Prior Month    Bill Date
StackOver   8657.00 2022-07-01  8657.00 2022-06-01
StackOver   8657.00 2022-06-01  8657.00 2022-05-01
StackOver   8657.00 2022-05-01  8657.00 2022-04-01
StackOver   8657.00 2022-04-01  8657.00 2022-03-01
StackOver   8657.00 2022-03-01  8657.00 2022-02-01
StackOver   8657.00 2022-02-01  8657.00 2022-01-01
StackOver   8657.00 2022-01-01  8657.00 2021-12-01
StackOver   640.00  2021-12-01  8657.00 2022-01-25
StackOver   8657.00 2021-12-01  640.00  2021-11-01
StackOver   8657.00 2021-11-01  8657.00 2021-10-01
StackOver   8657.00 2021-10-01  8657.00 2021-09-01
StackOver   8657.00 2021-09-01  8657.00 2021-08-01
StackOver   8657.00 2021-08-01  8657.00 2021-07-01
StackOver   8657.00 2021-07-01  8657.00 2021-06-01
StackOver   8657.00 2021-06-01  8657.00 2021-05-01
StackOver   8657.00 2021-05-01  8657.00 2021-04-01
StackOver   8657.00 2021-04-01  8657.00 2021-03-01
StackOver   8657.00 2021-03-01  0.00    2021-02-01
```

Note two entries on 12-2021 (lines 8 and 9) causing the LAG incorrectly show the bill date on line 8, but correct on line 9. And the EP_Sum of both line 8 and 9 should be a total in one row, not separate.

Edit: attached pic didn't work, so added result as text table.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Do your grouping in a derived table or CTE, then use LAG on the result.

Comment: Stu, I figured a CTE would be the way but not sure how to word it correctly. Do you know how? @Stu

Comment: Table structures (create table statements), sample data (insert statments) and desired output from the sample would go a long way to making this easier to understand.